# Не могу найти class в коде элемента

Tags: python, requests, bs4

Пишу парсер на python, с библиотеками requests, BeautifulSoup4. Имеется сайт с цитатами, которые нужно вытащить:
https://pikacho.ru/luchshie-motiviruyushchie-citaty-velikih-lyudej/ .

Вот код:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://pikacho.ru/luchshie-motiviruyushchie-citaty-velikih-lyudej/'

page = requests.get(url)

citates = []

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

citates = soup.findAll('p', class_ ='необходимый класс')

print (citates)
```

Проблема заключается в том, что обычно класс располагается сразу после тега, но здесь сразу же за тегом идет текст. Я пробовал найти другие сайты, но они построены похоже. Также я перепробовал несколько встречающихся по коду сайта классов. Если не сложно покажите где находить классы на подобных сайтах. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Заметил, что цитаты находятся в тегах `p` с тегом `strong`, в котором указывается автор, сами теги в элементе с классом `entry-inner`

Получился такой скрипт:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

rs = requests.get('https://pikacho.ru/luchshie-motiviruyushchie-citaty-velikih-lyudej/')
root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')

citates = [p.text for p in root.select('.entry-inner > p') if p.strong]
print(citates)
```